# Agregar nuevas columnas en un dataframe con pandas Series.str.extract

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

tengo un dataframe inicial(**df**) el cual tiene 3 columnas(**nombres**, **datos** y **vendor**). Desde la columna **datos** obtengo 3 nuevas columnas, extrayendo la información con **pandas.Series.str.extract** y **regex** en tres grupos: **IP1**, **IP2** y **mensaje**. El dataframe final solo deber tener la columnas **nombre**, **IP1**, **IP2**, **mensaje** y **vendor**. En el código que adjunto logro hacer todo esto creando otro dataframe de paso(**df1**), luego concatenando y finalmente borrando la columna **datos**. Pero me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma más eficiente de hacer la inserción de las 3 nuevas columnas en el dataframe resultante en la posición que necesito y borrar la columna **datos** en un solo paso. Quizás con el **pandas.DataFrame.apply**?.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

nombres = ['router1', 'router2', 'router3', 'router4', 'router5']

datos = ['IP1=10.176.39.100, IP2=10.176.49.188, mensaje=Puerto 22',
         'IP1=10.176.39.101, IP2=10.176.49.182, mensaje=Puerto 21',
         'IP1=10.176.39.102, IP2=10.176.49.176, mensaje=Puerto 18',
         'IP1=10.176.39.103, IP2=10.176.49.134, mensaje=Puerto 16',
         'IP1=10.176.39.104, IP2=10.176.49.145, mensaje=Puerto 17']

vendor = ['disco', 'kunyper', 'juawei', 'disco', 'kunyper']

df = pd.DataFrame({'nombres':nombres, 'datos':datos, 'vendor':vendor})

df

    nombres                                             datos    vendor
0   router1 IP1=10.176.39.100, IP2=10.176.49.188, mensaje=...   disco
1   router2 IP1=10.176.39.101, IP2=10.176.49.182, mensaje=...   kunyper
2   router3 IP1=10.176.39.102, IP2=10.176.49.176, mensaje=...   juawei
3   router4 IP1=10.176.39.103, IP2=10.176.49.134, mensaje=...   disco
4   router5 IP1=10.176.39.104, IP2=10.176.49.145, mensaje=...   kunyper


df1 = df['datos'].str.extract(r"""IP1=(?P<IP1>[^,]+),\sIP2=
                            (?P<IP2>[^,]+),\smensaje=(?P<mensaje>\w+\s\d+)""" , flags=re.VERBOSE)

df1

              IP1             IP2     mensaje
0   10.176.39.100   10.176.49.188   Puerto 22
1   10.176.39.101   10.176.49.182   Puerto 21
2   10.176.39.102   10.176.49.176   Puerto 18
3   10.176.39.103   10.176.49.134   Puerto 16
4   10.176.39.104   10.176.49.145   Puerto 17

df

df = pd.concat([df, df1], join='inner', axis=1)

df.drop(['datos'], axis=1)

    nombres  vendor           IP1             IP2   mensaje
0   router1 disco   10.176.39.100   10.176.49.188   Puerto 22
1   router2 kunyper 10.176.39.101   10.176.49.182   Puerto 21
2   router3 juawei  10.176.39.102   10.176.49.176   Puerto 18
3   router4 disco   10.176.39.103   10.176.49.134   Puerto 16
4   router5 kunyper 10.176.39.104   10.176.49.145   Puerto 17

df = df[['nombres','IP1','IP2','mensaje','vendor']]

df

    nombres           IP1             IP2   mensaje      vendor
0   router1 10.176.39.100   10.176.49.188   Puerto 22   disco
1   router2 10.176.39.101   10.176.49.182   Puerto 21   kunyper
2   router3 10.176.39.102   10.176.49.176   Puerto 18   juawei
3   router4 10.176.39.103   10.176.49.134   Puerto 16   disco
4   router5 10.176.39.104   10.176.49.145   Puerto 17   kunyper
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución con menos pasos es la siguiente:

```py
# Creamos 3 nuevas columnas ("IP1", "IP2" y "mensaje"),
# cuyos valores son el resultado de la función "extract".
df[["IP1", "IP2", "mensaje"]] = df["datos"].str.extract(
    r"IP1=(?P<IP1>[^,]+),\sIP2=(?P<IP2>[^,]+),\smensaje=(?P<mensaje>\w+\s\d+)"
)

# Filtramos "df" seleccionando columnas
df = df[["nombres", "IP1", "IP2", "mensaje", "vendor"]]
```

`df` queda así:

```
   nombres            IP1            IP2    mensaje   vendor
0  router1  10.176.39.100  10.176.49.188  Puerto 22    disco
1  router2  10.176.39.101  10.176.49.182  Puerto 21  kunyper
2  router3  10.176.39.102  10.176.49.176  Puerto 18   juawei
3  router4  10.176.39.103  10.176.49.134  Puerto 16    disco
4  router5  10.176.39.104  10.176.49.145  Puerto 17  kunyper
```

Comment: Tienes razón, me funcionó perfectamente. Muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada, me alegra haber ayudado.